# Is there a preferred way to order floating-point operands?

Tags: c, floating-point

Suppose I have a very small `float a` (for instance `a=0.5`) that enters the following expression:

```
6000.f * a * a;
```

Does the order of the operands make any difference? Is it better to write

```
6000.f * (a*a);
```

Or even

```
float result = a*a;
result *= 6000.f;
```

I've checked the classic [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19422-01/819-3693/ncg_goldberg.html) but couldn't find anything.

**Is there an optimal way to order operands in a floating point operation?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It really depends on the values and your goals. For instance if `a` is very small, `a*a` might be zero, whereas `6000.0*a*a` (which means `(6000.0*a)*a`) could still be nonzero. For avoiding overflow and underflow, the general rule is to apply the associative law to first perform multiplications where the operands' logs have opposite sign, which means squaring first is generally a worst strategy. On the other hand, for performance reasons, squaring first might be a very good strategy if you can reuse the value of the square. You may encounter yet another issue, which could matter more for correctness than overflow/underflow issues if your numbers will never be very close to zero or infinity: certain multiplications may be guaranteed to have exact answers, while others involve rounding. In general you'll get the most accurate results by minimizing the number of rounding steps that happen.

Comment: "operands' logs have opposite sign" means that one of the operands is > 1 and the other one is < 1.

Answer (score 4):

The optimal way depends on the purpose, really.

First of all, multiplication is faster than division.

So if you have to write `a = a / 2;`, it is better to write `a = a * 0.5f;`.
Your compiler is usually smart enough to replace division with multiplication on constants if the results is the same, but it will not do that with variables of course.

Sometimes, you can optimize a bit by replacing divisions with multiplications, but there may be problems with precision.

Some other operations may be faster but less precise.
Let's take an example.

```
float f = (a * 100000) / (b * 10);
float g = (a / b) * (100000 / 10);
```

These are mathematically equivalent but the result can be a little different.
The first uses two multiplication and one division, the second uses one division and one multiplication. In both cases there may be a loss in precision, it depends on the size of a and b, if they are small values first works better, if they are large values second works better

Then... if you have several constants and you want speed, group contants together.

```
float a = 6.3f * a * 2.0f * 3.1f;
```

Just write

```
a = a * (6.3f * 2.0f * 3.1f);
```

Some compiler optimize well, some other optimize less, but in both cases there is no risk in keeping all constants together.

After we say this we should talk for hours on how processors works.
Even the same family like intel works in a different way between generations!
Some compilers uses SSE instructions, some other doesn't.
Some processor supports SSE2, some SSE, some only MMX... some system don't have an FPU neither!
Each system do better some calculations than other, finding a common thing is hard.

You should just write a readable code, clean and simple, without worryng too much about these unpredictable very low level optimizations.

If your expression looks complicated, do some algebra and\or go to wolframalpha search engine and ask him to optimize that for you :)

Said that, you don't really need to declare one variable and replace its content over and over, compiler usually can optimize less in this situation.

```
a = 5 + b;
a /= 2 * c;
a += 2 - c;
a *= 7;
```

just write your expression avoiding this mess :)

```
a = ((5 + b) / (2 * c) + 2 - c) * 7;
```

About your specific example, `6000.f * a * a`, just write it as you write it, no need to change it; it is fine as it is.

Comment: The compiler **cannot** replace multiplication with division unless the result will be exactly the same, and this is rare.  It can only really happen for powers of two.  (However, `-ffast-math` on GCC will enable such optimizations.)

Comment: I was talking about division with constants, microsoft visual C do that if there is no risk in doing that. It replaces a x /= 2; with x *= 0.5f; and this is safe from all point of view.

Comment: As I said, it can only happen with powers of two.  So `x / 3` cannot be changed to multiplication (unless `x` is an integer, of course...)

Comment: Yes of course, power of two can be encoded in floating point without risk of losing precision, other kind of decimal may be not, but i guess it depends on the compiler and as you pointed out on the optimization settings. Microsoft visual C have a flag that ask if you want precise or fast floating point operations.

Comment: For the same reason as for the division->multiplication transformation, the compiler cannot transform `6.3f * a * 2.0f * 3.1f` into `a * (6.3f * 2.0f * 3.1f)` because it is not the same thing. A compiler that does this transformation without the the programmer prompting it to with an option is not an optimizing compiler, it's a wrong compiler. I agree that the programmer can do the transformation himself and it's usually fine for him, but the reason the compiler doesn't do it is not lack of optimization.

Answer (score 3):

Not typically, no.

That being said, if you're doing multiple operations with large values, it *may* make sense to order them in a way that avoids overflows or reduces precision errors, based on their [precedence and associativity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++#Operator_precedence), if the algorithm provides a way to make that obvious.  This would, however, require advance knowledge of the values involved, and not just be based on the syntax.

Comment: Plus on modern processors you don't really know for sure what order the operations are executed or even if they will be executed serially.

Comment: @MartyTPS: Irrelevant.  The processor computes the same result as if it had executed the operations serially.

Comment: Pay attention, Dietrich.  The question posted was whether changing the order was relevant.  It is not necessarily under your control in the end so YES it is IRRELEVANT

Comment: @MartyTPS: You're wrong. The order is under your control. The compiler/cpu cannot reorder floating point operations in any way that would change the result, and for most purposes, that means simply they cannot reorder floating point at all.

Comment: @MartyTPS The person who told you about Out-of-Order execution in modern processors meant that independent instructions may be executed in an order that differs from the instruction stream. Processors do not reorder dependent instructions. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-order_execution

Answer (score 3):

There are indeed algorithms to minimize cumulative error in a sequence of floating-point operations. One such is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm. Others exist for other operations: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake-papers/related/Priest.ps.