# Why does adding positive and negative double values in different order produces different result?

Tags: c#, .net, double, addition

I have seen this behavior when I try adding double values where one of the value is a negative double, the order in which I add these values apparently does matter. Here's my test

```
    double val1 = -0.06, val2 = 0.04, val3 = 0.02;
    double resOrder1 = val1 + val2 + val3;
    double resOrder2 = val2 + val3 + val1;
    Console.WriteLine(resOrder1); //3.46944695195361E-18
    Console.WriteLine(resOrder2); //0
```

Am I missing some key principle here? Moreover, how do I make sure I get true for `if(resOrder1 == 0){}` regardless the addition order. And no I don't want to change the data type to decimal.

Comment: [What every computer scientist should know about floating-point arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: That's because not all double values can be represented exactly.  That's why you should test doubles against a tolerance range instead of an exact value.

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/a/7936044/106159